# Why passing an lvalue as an rvalue argument fails?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

Passing lvalue reference as an rvalue reference argument does not compile. Compiler could create a temporary object with its copy constructor and pass it as an rvalue, but it does not. Still, it does call the constructor, if types do not match.

I'm interested, why does it works that way? Which design logic is here in the C++ standard, that forces the compiler to treat copy-constructor in a different way?

```
void do_smth(string && s)
{}

void f(const char * s)
{
  do_smth(s); // passes a temporary string constructed from const char*
}

void g(const string & s)
{
  do_smth(s); // does not compile
}

void h(const string & s)
{
  do_smth(string(s)); // ok again
}
```

What should I do if I do not want to implement the second signature `do_smth(const string &)`? Should I use pass-by-value `void do_smth(string s)` instead?

What are other differences betweeen by-value `void do_smth(string s)` and rvalue-reference `void do_smth(string && s)`, given the object `string` has move constructor?

Comment: Yes, pass-by-value would be quite useful here.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253572/implementing-rvalue-references-as-parameters-in-function-overloads/51253882#51253882).

Answer (score 4):

This is the whole point of rvalue references. They bind to *rvalues*, and **not** to *lvalues*.

That is how you ensure that the overload you wanted is invoked, when you have both an lvalue version and an rvalue version. For example, a copy constructor vs a move constructor.

It's a feature.

Also, your lvalue is `const`, which does not match the signature of `do_smth` even if it did not take an rvalue reference.

If you want `do_smth` to be able to take *either* kind of expression, either make it take a `const string&`, or make it a template and have it take a *[forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552345/560648)* `T&&` (which looks like an rvalue reference but kind of isn't).

If you want `do_smth` to *store its own version of the string* then have it take a value: you can still avoid a copy if needs be by using `std::move` at the callsite (or by passing an rvalue, which will trigger the string's own move constructor).

See how all options are available and elegant, due to how the rvalue reference binding rules are made? It all fits together.

Deciding what to allow `do_smth` to take entirely depends on what "smth" it is going to "do", and only you can say what that is.

Comment: What do you mean "ensure that the overload you wanted is invoked, when you have both an lvalue version and an rvalue version"? If I made `void do_smth(const char* s)` signature as well, the compiler would call it in f() instead of contructing a temporary object, would not it? Why lvalue and rvalue overloads are different in that way, and so, compiler does not call copy constructor to convert lvalue to rvalue automatically, when there is no lvalue version of the signature?

Comment: @RomanMaltsev Sorry, I don't understand what "differences" you're referring to. Yes, if you pass an lvalue `const char*` to a function accepting a `const char*`, that'll work. That's the pass-by-value case. You could also pass it to a function accepting a `const char*&` (i.e. an lvalue reference). You could not pass it to a function accepting a `const char*&&` (i.e. an rvalue reference).

Comment: I mean, why `string(const char*)` constructor is 'good' to silently convert const char* to a temporary string and pass it as rvalue. but `string(const string &) is 'bad' constructor for a same silent conversion?

Comment: @RomanMaltsev Technically the reason is because one implicit conversion is allowed. `std::string` has an implicit (i.e. non-explicit) constructor from `const char*`, but copy-construction is never an implicit conversion. Your question whether this makes sense is valid though.

Comment: @MaxLanghof What do you mean "copy-construction is never an implicit conversion"? A copy constuctor can be either marked with explicit keyword or not marked. When marked, it also prevents automatic copying in passing-by-value, so the code in g would not compile even when `void do_smth(string s)` signature was used instead of rvalue signature. So, when copying an argument to pass it by value, the copy constructor is called implicitly, just as a conversion constructor. So, copy-constructor should have worked or not worked the same way for string and string&&, if it were about explicit keyword.

Answer (score 0):

in *h*  you give a *non const* copy of the *const* string, so the *const* disappears contrarily to the *g* case

of course with `void do_smth(string s){...}` the copy is made at the call and both *const* and *non const string* can be given in argument